# How to shift 3.3V to 5V with 3.3V provided only

Tags: voltage, nmos

I am trying to control 5V LED using ESP32's 3.3V GPIO. I researched voltage shifting using NMOS but could not get it to correctly output 5V when simulated in Tinkercad.

[image]

Is it possible to accomplish this without a 5V supply? What am I doing wrong here?

Edit:
LED I got is [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01LXZSV2N/ref=sspa_dk_detail_2?psc=1&pd_rd_i=B01LXZSV2N&pd_rd_w=hAXXr&content-id=amzn1.sym.89ee1d2e-380f-4a05-89e5-d22eb0a17762&pf_rd_p=89ee1d2e-380f-4a05-89e5-d22eb0a17762&pf_rd_r=JY1V7JDVYCG4V8GWN336&pd_rd_wg=qfdlZ&pd_rd_r=9d901bb4-46a0-46fe-b2f1-9c4b264b07c5&s=toys-and-games&sp_csd=d2lkZ2V0TmFtZT1zcF9kZXRhaWxfdGhlbWF0aWM&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUExOTdHQThMNTZFOVJFJmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwMzc0MzM1M1ZLTTJJM1FSS1REWCZlbmNyeXB0ZWRBZElkPUEwMDYxNzIxMjNYT1NKSkdaRjBMNCZ3aWRnZXROYW1lPXNwX2RldGFpbF90aGVtYXRpYyZhY3Rpb249Y2xpY2tSZWRpcmVjdCZkb05vdExvZ0NsaWNrPXRydWU=](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01LXZSV2N)

Comment: Does your ESP32 board have a 5V *power* output pin available to power your level shifter? If not, you'll need to generate 5 V somehow.

Comment: @nanofarad No it does not. It only has 3.3V and VBAT, which I believe is also 3.3v. What's the usual way to generate 5V in such system?

Comment: Is it really a 5V LED? Nearly all LEDs will work from 1.6V to 3.3V, depending on their color and chemistry. You have not specified your LED, which is definitely something you should have included.

Comment: @EdinFifić I edited my post with the LED I got

Comment: Not enough detail, but they seem to be standard LEDs with a resistor. They should work at 3.3V but with significantly less brightness. You could probably open them and replace the resistors with lower resistances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *truly* require 5v and only have a 3.3v supply, then you should *generate* a 5v supply using a [boost converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_converter).

However, many LEDs (even those whose datasheets specify 5v) can safely operate with a 3.3v supply. Perhaps your LED will work at 3.3v with no changes to the circuit.

You may need to reduce the resistor value to increase the LED brightness after reducing the supply voltage.

Comment: Rather than a boost converter, a small charge pump, e.g [this](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3661), a MAX682, or similar might be easier to integrate for a small, light load depending on power/space/cost requirements.

Comment: Great suggestion! I was lumping charge pumps and voltage multipliers in the same category as boost converters in my head, but they're indeed different things and charge pumps are probably more suitable to this kind of project.

Comment: The resistor is probably built into the button, so it can't be changed. It will probably still work, but won't be as bright. Maybe not bright enough.

Comment: reportedly  `The red led is actually two leds wired serially with 200ohm resistor while blue led wires two blue leds in parallel with same 200ohm resistror`  - red will probably not not work well from 3.3V  green and yellow are probably same as red

Comment: @nanofarad This is good! Fo you know if there an IC that I can boost to a varying voltage? For example depending on a configuration boost 3.3v to 5V or 3.3v to 12v?

Comment: @Megool Not off the top of my head, but plenty of boost ICs have adjustments of various types. You might need to shop around the wide variety that's out there.